# Strange timeout on php curl crawl

Tags: php, curl, web-crawler

Hey trying to run a curl script to crawl a website but it keeps timing out. It works locally but not on this server. everything is setup correctly as far as I'm aware.

note i have replaced the sites full name with XXXXX for this code sample.

```php
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$url = "http://xxxxx.eu/search?f=b" ;

$header = getHeaders(0);
$request = array();
$request['url'] = $url ;
$request['method'] = 'get' ;
$request['header'] = $header ;
echo getPageCURL($request);

die();


function getHeaders($content_length=0)
{

    $header = array();
    $header[] = "Host: xxxxx.eu";
    $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate";
    $header[] = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0";
    $header[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";

    if($content_length>10) $header[] = "Content Size: ".$content_length;
    $header[] = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8";  
    $header[] = "Content-Encoding: gzip"; 
    $header[] = "Vary: Accept-Encoding"; 
    $header[] = "Content-Length: 22";
    $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";


    return $header;
}


function getPageCURL($request) 
{

    $page = '';
    $verified = '';
    $page_type = 'O';
    $filter = true;
    $page_header = 0;
    $followlocation = true;
    $cookies = true;
    $bad_url = false;
    if(is_array($request))
    {
        foreach($request as $request_key=>$request_value)
            $$request_key = $request_value;
    }
    else $url = $request;
    if(empty($url)) return '';
    $url = str_replace(' ', '+', $url);

    //echo  "\nCalling : ".$url;

    for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
    {
        $curl = curl_init();
        if(isset($header) && is_array($header))
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
        if(isset($referer) && !empty($referer))
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
        if(isset($ssl))
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        if(isset($method) && $method=='post')
        {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            if(isset($post_data) && $post_data!='')
            {
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
            }
        }

        if($cookies)
        {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
        }

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);                          
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate'); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, $page_header);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $followlocation);


        $page = curl_exec($curl);


        if(($page===false || trim($page) == '' || empty($page)) && (curl_errno($curl) == 6 || curl_errno($curl) == 7))
        {
            curl_close ($curl);
            //echo "\nNetwork problem...";
            sleep(10);
            $i--;
            continue;
        }
        else if(curl_errno($curl) == 6)
        {
            file_put_contents('cu_failed-'.time().'.txt', $page, FILE_APPEND);
        }


        curl_close ($curl);
    }
    $page = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), " ", $page);
    return $page;
}


?>
```

If I try to just do a basic wget on the site in question I get this repsonse:

```
root@vps38132:~# wget http://xxxxx.eu
--2013-10-31 10:30:02--  http://xxxxx.eu/
Resolving xxxxxx.eu (xxxxxx.eu)... 31.7.58.171, 31.7.58.172, 31.7.58.170
Connecting to xxxxxx.eu (xxxxxx.eu)|31.7.58.171|:80...
```

any ideas ? I am able to curl/wget other sites just not this one whats happening?

Comment: try to ping the ip address to your command prompt. check if there is a timeout issue.

Comment: ping works fine seriously bugging me :(

Comment: firewall issue on the server side?

Comment: there side. if you can access the ip address on the browser probably it will work. maybe something is blocking the curl from connecting to the server ip.

Comment: So file_get_contents() does what, return empty

Answer (score 1):

when you make curl call then authentication is required . so you below code after curl initialization.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ) ;
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username:password');

let me know if required more detail.